# How to find the best fitting function for a y-x non-linear relationship

Tags: python, non-linear-regression, best-fit-curve

I have two variables, y being the number of targets achieved and x the number of individuals involved in the operation. The relationship is positive and non-linear (there are only so many individuals you can add before the returns of adding individuals are diminishing), however I am not sure what is the function of x that best predict y.

Using Python, I would like to find the best fitting line/function and identify the maximum of the function to advise how many individuals include in each team to achieve the maximum number of targets [controlling for different variables]

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since the set of all non-linear monotonically increasing functions is probably infinite, you will have to restrict yourself to some finite set of functions. Either some common ones (quadratic, third-order polynomial, log, exp) or maybe all Chebyshev polynomials up to order something. or possibly something more complex.

Comment: @KahntM, not much yet! I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: @Graipher, so I still need to test how different functions perfom fitting the relationship? (E.g. comparing the differenet sum of squared residuals?)

Comment: @FilippoSebastio: Yes, you will have to fit each function before you know if it fits your data...obviously. Even functions that can only be made positive-semidefinite but are not monotonically increasing can be used by using their CDF. If you can rescale your problem into the [0, 1] domain, the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) (or rather its CDF) might be general enough for it to be able to describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ridge-regression` with `kernels`. kernels helps in transforming `linear` function to `non-linear` function without changing its actual form. This is what **Graipher** was pointing.

Here is a [script](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_compare_gpr_krr.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-compare-gpr-krr-py), which shows an example to use it.

Also, these selection comes with experience and understanding. You can also guess closely(eg. which polynomial can fit in), by visualizing the function form.